# admod ad is on top of page and I want at bottom

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Hi guys below is my code, ad is still on top even I defined the LinearLayout gravity as bottom.

How can I move it to the bottom ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3322077143918557/4267166755" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
    </ListView>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you want to add the admod in the bottom or the whole layout?

Comment: yes I want at bottom of whole layout.

Answer (score 0):

Put the AdView ad the end of the LinearLayout. The gravity does not change the order of the items in the layout.